# Design patterns for building a house, composition?

Tags: design-patterns

I am refactoring a code base, which is something like a house. A house has walls, windows, doors, etc. Currently, everything is put inside house class, such as

```
class House {
   public:
     void setDoorColor(int color);
     void setDoorWidth(int width);

     void setWallColor(int color);
     void setWallWidth(int width);
     ...
   private:
     int doorColor;
     int doorWidth;

     int wallColor;
     int wallHeight;
     ...
}
```

So, it is quite messy. What I can think about is using something like composition, for example,

```
class House {
   private:
      Wall wall;
      Window window;
      ...
}
```

Where to put public APIs? In each component, say windows relevant APIs inside Window? The thing is `House` is passed to many other functions as an argument, such `void foo(const House& house, int, double)`. How to use `House` to access `door` and `wall`? such as `house.getDoor().getDoorColor()`? Any good ideas?

Comment: You tagged this as design-patterns but your solution is simple composition, not really composite design pattern which I think could be interesting solution but not knowing the full context.

Answer (score 1):

Your suggestion is good, use public getter, setter method to all private variables. Then you can access like you mentioned.

```
class House {
   private:
      Wall wall;
      Window window;

    public:
     void setWall(Wall );
     Wall getWall ();

     void setWindow (Window  window);
     Window  getWindow ();

}
```

Comment: I usually take it as a hint that the design could be improved when I see setters. Instead of getters and setters, the class should have a meaningful service interface that models operations on the internal state.

Comment: `House` is passing around to other functions. Other functions can first get a reference from `House` and then use this reference to access its methods. Am I on the right track?  such as in `foo()`: `Wall wall = house->getWall(); wall->setColor(Gray)`?

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping primitive types in classes like `Wall` or `Window` make perfect sense. You definitely should do that, because when you group some ints and strings together and give them a name you start to think about constraints this name implies.

For example, when you have class `Wall` does method `Delete` seem like appropriate for this class? Well, no it doesn't. More suiting would be `Demolish`, right? That's what happens when you stop thinking primitives and start thinking classes.

That brings me to my next remark. You should not just make class with properties of types `Wall`, `Window` or `Door`. You can make `House` class your access point to other objects through meaningful methods! Would you rather see code like

```
Wall wall = new Wall();
house->setWall(wall);
```

or

```
Wall wall = house->buildWall();
```

Which one tells you more about what's really happening? What's *setting* a wall? Building it looks more intuitive, right? Designing this kind of API is unfortunately pretty hard. Why? Without any more business context there is no way to tell whether you should go with `Wall wall = house->buildWall();` or maybe `constructionCrew->buildWall(house);`. Does house should know where all the walls are or every wall should know where it stands?

Even with dilemmas like this, you should be able to write code using actual objects (so classes with **behaviours**, not only data structures with getters and setters!). I think you can tell by yourself judging only by this short example, that code of this type is easier to read and maintain.

This is really broad subject - I would recommend doing more reading about this!

Comment: Thanks a lot! Any suggestions on reading, such as books, blogs, etc. I am having gang of four book, but did not read it. :)

Comment: @SuperBald sorry for late answer! I would recommend you reading Implementing Domain-Driven Design by Vaughn Vernon. I liked the way Vaughn writes his code very much. It really change my way of thinking about good object-oriented code. It's quite long and discusses domain driven design, which might be not so interesting so much for you right now, but it's really worth reading.